# how to configure node-pushserver in sails js?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, sails.js, sails-mongo, sails.io.js

I am using sails js with mongodb.I need to implement push notification for android and ios. how can i implement it. I searched lot of things in internet regarding push notifications in sails js  but i didn't find any useful resources for implementing push notifications in sails js. I tried node-push server but didn't get how to configure node-pushserver in sails js so can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer for my above question on git hub by Maxime Robert.

Here i am pasting the answer just because it might be useful for others who are facing the similar problem.

```
Hi,

node-pushserver is NOT in sails.js and shouldn't be hard-linked to any other 
development. 

It is meant to be used as a standalone application requiring node.js and 
mongodb as dependencies.

Your application should only interact with node-pushserver via its REST API.
```